# Overriding a computed property that returns an Optional value with one that returns a non-Optional

Tags: swift, overriding, computed-properties

The following compiles and runs with no issue on my Xcode 9.2 running Swift 4:

```
class ParentWithComputedOptional {
    var computedOptional: Int? { return nil }
}

class ChildThatUnwraps: ParentWithComputedOptional {
    override var computedOptional: Int { return 10 }
}
```

Notice that in the parent, `computedOptional` is an `Int?`, but in the child it is overridden to be an `Int`. Furthermore, the `override` keyword has to be specified for the code to compile. This was tested on both Playground and a proper project.

Is this expected behaviour? If yes, is there a relevant page in Apple's documentation for this scenario?

Comment: You made an interesting finding. I think this makes perfect sense because whenever you use the parent type, you expect non-nil or nil, which is fulfilled by the child type always providing non-nil. It would not work the other way around (non-optional in the parent, optional in the child). In a way, this reminds me of the Liskov substitution principle (which is more concerned with semantics than syntax, but still applies here IMO). I didn't find this "phenomenon" being mentioned explicitly in the language guides, but I hope a Swift pro comes around and points us to the right pages :)

Comment: @dr_barto The issue with this is that when accessing an instance of `ChildThatUnwraps`, you don't unwrap `computedOptional`, whereas you _do_ have to perform unwrapping if you cast the object to `ParentWithComputedOptional` - even though it's the same property.

Comment: My bad, you are right of course. This makes it just more interesting...

Comment: Oh. It works not just with `computed properties`, but with `functions` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular case of overriding doesn't appear to be documented anywhere in the official language guide, but is mentioned in Swift's [changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for the 4.0 release (look for SR-1529).

---

This topic deserve some additional information:

Actually, this behavior isn't limited to optionals, but also applies to other [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) types, as long as the overridden property is a computed read-only one in the derived class.
For instance, the following code will compile as well in Swift 4.1.

```
class Animal {}
class Koala: Animal {}

class Foo {
  var x: Animal { return Animal() }
}
class Bar: Foo {
  override var x: Koala { return Koala() }
}
```

This is a edge case that doesn't violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because the Base class' property is a read-only computed one. Hence, if an instance of `Bar` were to be held in a variable of type `Foo`, there'd be no way to mutate its `x` property so that it'd create a type error when downcasting the object to a variable of type `Bar`.